# Encrypt second hard disk with same password

Tags: security, encryption, luks, dmcrypt

I installed Ubuntu 14 LTS with disk encryption (selected during installation). I have two questions:

1- What is encryption algorithm of current encrypted disk?

2- I have a second hard disk and I want to encrypt it with same algorithm and same password, so that after boot Ubuntu can mount it automatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the tool cryptsetup already installed.

To show details of the current cipher you can run the following command:

```
sudo cryptsetup status sda5_crypt
```

Replacing sda5_crypt with the name of your encrypted volume.
You should see an output similar to this:

```
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 512 bits
  device:  /dev/sda5
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    482697216 sectors
  mode:    read/write
  flags:   discards
```

Comment: Thank you. Well, do you know how can I encrypt my second hard disk as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I wrote an answer in [Initramfs + Luks - only one password prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636503/initramfs-luks-only-one-password-prompt/636515#636515)  that answers your second question, too: There is a script included with luks that you can use to derive a key for device B from an opened device A. Hence you only have to type the password for your root device and the keys for all other devices will be calculated from that. (But: The devices **won't** have the same passwords, unless you add the same password to each one manually.)