# Initramfs + Luks - only one password prompt

Tags: boot, encryption, lvm, luks

## What I want to achieve:

- Being asked for a password, only once during boot time;
- The other (non-root) partitions to use the keyfile inside the `/root/` directory.

## What I have achieved so far:

- **(A)** The system booting, but asking for password twice (once for `/`, and once for `/usr`).
- Or: **(B)** the system not booting, asking for password once, but then refusing the mount `/usr` saying it cannot found the LVM group/volume. I get dropped to shell, and can see that `/root/.keyfile` is unavailable. `/` has not been mounted yet.

### Configuration

File: `/etc/crypttab`

#### Case A

`sdc3_crypt /dev/sdc3 none luks
md0_crypt /dev/md0 none luks`

#### Case B

`sdc3_crypt /dev/sdc3 none luks
md0_crypt /dev/md0 /root/.keyfile luks`

### What totally didn't work

- Creating script files to manually luksOpen the required drive: those in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount` are called before `/` is available, but those in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom` are called after it wants to open `/usr` (and therefore it is too late).

Comment: The order of the entries in `fstab` matters. Are you sure that you have `/` mounted before `/usr` in `fstab`?

Comment: That is a good question. I assume `/` is at the top, before anything else. I would have to wait until I get home, in order to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

On [this wiki page](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LUKS/Schl%C3%BCsselableitung) (in german, I sadly didn't find an equivalent in english) it is suggested that you use the script `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived` to generate a key from the opened root device. I will try to translate the important parts, but I have **NOT** tried the procedure.

To add the key, you would have to execute (as root)

```
mkdir /mnt/ram && mount -t ramfs -o size=1m ramfs /mnt/ram && chmod 600 /mnt/ram
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived <root_dev> > /mnt/ram/tmp.key && cryptsetup luksAddKey <usr_dev> /mnt/ram/tmp.key && rm /mnt/ram/tmp.key
umount /mnt/ram && rmdir /mnt/ram
```

where `<root_name>` is the name of your root device as displayed in `/dev/mapper` (probably `sdc3_crypt`), and `<usr_dev>` the device where `/usr` is on (probably `/dev/md0`).

The line for crypttab is

```
  <usr_name>         UUID=<UUID>          <root_name>           luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived
```

remember to run

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

after changing crypttab.

**You should keep a "normal" password for your usr device, otherwise you won't be able to open it in case your root device is damaged.**